# Plugging in a GPU into a PCI slot via a PCI-e to PCI converter: is it possible?

Tags: gpu, pci-express, pci

First of all, this is for a GPGPU project so I only need a **very small amount of bandwidth**. The bandwidth for PCI and PCI-e 1x slots are several orders of magnitude more than I need.

Some people have made a [PCI-e 1x to PCI converter](http://www.dabs.com/products/startech-com-pci-to-pcie-adapter-card-6PG2.html). With some simple hacks I can make a PCI-e 16x to PCI-e 1x converter.

The question is, if I plug in a GPU (Radeon 5870) into the PCI slot using this method, will it be recognised by the computer's BIOs and by the AMD fglrx proprietary driver?

Comment: Do it already and post the results.

Comment: Fine, it worked exactly as expected, managed to get 4 5870's into one computer and started mining bitcoins on them at the same time (using poclbm)

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of this decentralized currency concept before. This is awesome! Btw, answer your own question and throw in some details (and sources) about PCI-e being backwards compatible with PCI.

Comment: Oops, this question is so old I forgot to read it properly; no, I did not try putting a PCI-e into PCI, but PCI-e 16x cards into PCI-e 1x slots by heavily modifying a 1x extender. I really do not think using a gfx card via a PCI slot will work unless you heavily modify the driver it runs on.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I haven't tried it but I see no reason why it shouldn't work. PCIe and PCI are much the same from a software perspective and the electrical differences can be easily handled by a bridge chip (which is what is on those adapter cards)